# Ionic native plugin not working after build --prod

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, ionic4

I implemented some ionic native plugins in an app (standard install and imported to app.module properly). When I tested it, it worked fine in my DevApp. After I built it with ionic build --prod and open it, my plugins are not working at all. I'm building it as an iOS app. Is there any steps I'm missing?

My steps:

1. create ionic 4 app
2. ionic cordova platform add ios
3. build my app and install plugins
4. test it on DevApp and it's fine
5. ionic build --prod (I'm thinking maybe this step is wrong? Should I build in other ways to make native plugins work or included on iOS device?)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not working is a vague statement, can you look into the logs for errors.

Comment: no error message in log. I have vibration and brightness plugin when I click they are simply just not responding